# Overriding a template file from a 3rd party module

Tags: overrides, magento-2.2.5

**What I know**

Overriding a template from `vendor/magento/<magento_module>` is straight-forward enough. So, to override a `magento_catalog` file I'd do:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Magento_Catalog/...
```

**Where I'm stuck**

However, 3rd party modules have a different file structure. If I were to override the below file, what would be my directory structure in `app/design`?

```
vendor/ebizmarts/sagepaysuite/view/frontend/web/template/payment/pi-form.html
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried a few variations like the ones below, but the override file doesn't seem to get read.

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Ebizmarts_Sagepaysuite/web/template/payment/pi-form.html
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Ebizmarts/Sagepaysuite/web/template/payment/pi-form.html
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Ebizmarts_Sagepaysuite/templates/payment/pi-form.html
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Ebizmarts/Sagepaysuite/templates/payment/pi-form.html
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite/templates/payment/pi-form.html
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Child>/Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite/web/template/payment/pi-form.html
```

Comment: Did you removed var/view_preprocessed and pub/static after your change and cleared cache?

Comment: Yup. Caching not the issue.

Comment: What is the module name? Can you show from module.xml?

Comment: `Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite` - I've just amended the sensitivity, but no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder name inside the theme is taken from the extensions composer.json file under the autoload -> psr4 value.

I have overwritten files for the same extension before and used the file path below:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/themename/Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite/web/template/payment/cc-form.html
```

After making the changes be sure to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade in your web root to clear all static files and then regenerate them.

Comment: Thanks for confirming DIR. Despite manually clearing caches, `bin/magento setup:upgrade` did the trick.

Comment: I have a similar need to override a html template in path ```app/code/MageWorx/SearchSuiteAutocomplete/view/frontend/web/template/autocomplete.html``` and the theme is ```app/design/frontend/Codazon/unlimited/drug_pharmacy```. I have copied modified file to ```app/design/frontend/Codazon/unlimited/drug_pharmacy/MageWorx/SearchSuiteAutocomplete/view/frontend/web/template/autocomplete.html``` . After clearing var/view_preprocessed and pub/static folders, caches and setup:upgrade, still no change is reflected in frontend. Are there any other steps I have to follow. Thanks